# Windows 10 Folder Permissions for Workgroup

Tags: permissions, windows-xp, windows-10, workgroup

I have a workgroup which has 3 computers in it.

1 of these is a Windows XP machine, the other 2 are Windows 10.

There is a folder on one of the Windows 10 machines which I need all these computers to access.

When I go into properties for that folder to add change permissions, I am unable to add the Windows XP machine by name.

After granting access to `Everyone`, the computers can access the folder.

Is there a way to add just give these workgroup computers access, and not every computer on the network?

Comment: Upgrade the xp machine and use a homegroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create the same username on all computer with the same password, and give the permission that way (username)

That way you secure the share as you will be sure only those person/login on those computers would got access, not everyone on that computer.